Hardware compatibility HPE Smart Array P440ar with Ubuntu server 24.04
Is the controller compatible with Ubuntu Server OS? How to check?
Thanks

HPE Smart Array P440ar is compatible with Ubuntu Server 24.04. HPE has provided packages for Ubuntu 24.04 in its official repositories. Unfortunately the instructions for installing it in Ubuntu are not up to date. This means that someone from HPE has to tell you which package to install (it looks like you need to install only one package) and how to install it in Ubuntu 24.04. Maybe HPE will tell you to install more than one package. You should check this with HPE before you do anything.
